# django 'F-expression' query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models, subject and visit. I'm trying to select visits where the age in months was over a certain amount, but cannot simply filter on age_months, as it is not a field, but rather a calculated value associated with the visit model.

We are getting age_months from a form and then trying to convert it to a date (subject birthdate plus the age in months converted to a timedelta) then use [F-filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) in our view to select visits where the visit_date is greater than this calculated subject age

Here is the code:

```
        vform = VisSearchForm(request.POST,prefix='v')
        if vform.is_valid():
            e = vform.cleaned_data
            vresults = Visit.objects.all()
            if e['age_months']:
                vresults.filter(visit_date__gt=F('subject__birthdate') + timedelta(days=30.44*e['age_months']))
```

the birthdate field is connected to the subject model, not the visit model and visit_date is connected to the visit model.

When I print the timedelta part I get a value, but when I print the **F('subject__birthdate') + timedelta(days=30.44*e['age_months'])**

I get

```
(+: (DEFAULT: ), 700 days, 2:52:48)
```

When what I want is the F('subject__birthdate') to return a date and not (+: (DEFAULT: )

Comment: have you found solution for this foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

It won't. The `F` object is a reference to a database field and holds absolutely no meaning outside the context of a database query.

Even when the query is built, it is still a reference to another database field, and doesn't hold an actual value.